# Login With Tumblr in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, tumblr

I am using tumbler login authentication via oauth. I am following this url: http://codegerms.com/login-with-tumblr-in-uiwebview-using-xcode-6-part-3/ 
for login authentication and get Access token and Secret Key for Tumblr API in iOS via login in UIWebview.

I am using this block of code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   // clientID = @"Tjta51N6kF6Oxmm1f3ytpUvMPRAE1bRgCgG90SOa0bJMlSlLeT";
   // secret = @"lrlQPNx3Yb1nRxp4qreYXvUURkGUmYCBoQacOmLTDRJAc7awRN";
    clientID = @"sdF0Y6bQoJYwfIB1Mp7WECwobAgnq5tmkRjo7OXyKHDg3opY7Y";
    secret = @"qJNGrRjyriZBeBhcgJz0MAcD9WAYXUW1tLbLrbYE4ZclzAUH9g";
    redirect   = @"tumblr://authorized";
    [self.WebView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.WebView setOpaque:NO];

    [self connectTumblr];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



-(void)connectTumblr {
    consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc]initWithKey:clientID secret:secret];


    NSURL* requestTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"];

    OAMutableURLRequest* requestTokenRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenUrl

                                                                               consumer:consumer

                                                                                  token:nil

                                                                                  realm:nil

                                                                      signatureProvider:nil] ;

    OARequestParameter* callbackParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_callback" value:redirect] ;

    [requestTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [requestTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:callbackParam]];

    OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init] ;

    [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:requestTokenRequest

                             delegate:self

                    didFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveRequestToken:data:)

                      didFailSelector:@selector(didFailOAuth:error:)];

}

- (void)didReceiveRequestToken:(OAServiceTicket*)ticket data:(NSData*)data {

    NSString* httpBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    requestToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:httpBody];

    NSURL* authorizeUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize"];

    OAMutableURLRequest* authorizeRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authorizeUrl

                                                                            consumer:nil

                                                                               token:nil

                                                                               realm:nil

                                                                   signatureProvider:nil];

    NSString* oauthToken = requestToken.key;

    OARequestParameter* oauthTokenParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_token" value:oauthToken] ;

    [authorizeRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:oauthTokenParam]];

    // UIWebView* webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    //  webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    //  [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:webView];



    // webView.delegate = self;

    [self.WebView loadRequest:authorizeRequest];

}
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"scheme: %@",[[request URL] scheme]);
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"tumblr"]) {

        // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query

        NSString* verifier = nil;

        NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

        for (NSString* param in urlParams) {

            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];

            if ([key isEqualToString:@"oauth_verifier"]) {

                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];

                break;

            }

        }

        if (verifier) {

            NSURL* accessTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"];

            OAMutableURLRequest* accessTokenRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:accessTokenUrl

                                                                                      consumer:consumer

                                                                                         token:requestToken

                                                                                         realm:nil

                                                                             signatureProvider:nil];

            OARequestParameter* verifierParam = [[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier" value:verifier];

            [accessTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            [accessTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObject:verifierParam]];

            OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

            [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:accessTokenRequest

                                     delegate:self

                            didFinishSelector:@selector(didReceiveAccessToken:data:)

                              didFailSelector:@selector(didFailOAuth:error:)];

        } else {

            // ERROR!

        }



        [webView removeFromSuperview];

        return NO;

    }

    return YES;

}


- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"webView error: %@",error);
    // ERROR!
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [spinner setHidden:NO];
    [spinner startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [spinner setHidden:YES];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}


- (void)didReceiveAccessToken:(OAServiceTicket*)ticket data:(NSData*)data {



    NSString* httpBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    accessToken = [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:httpBody];

    NSString *OAuthKey = accessToken.key;    // HERE YOU WILL GET ACCESS TOKEN

    NSString *OAuthSecret = accessToken.secret;  //HERE  YOU WILL GET SECRET TOKEN

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Tumblr Token"
                              message:OAuthSecret
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];




}
```

Every thing is working fine but when logged in then

```
if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"tumblr"]) {
}
```

should called in shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method
but the given condition is not satisfied. so that I am unable to verify oauth_verifier and unable to get accessToken.
Please Advice Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the response of requestTokenURL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be use **https** instead of **http** for every url of Tumblr.It will work perfectly.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes it.work perfectly for first time but when we call second time login then it's simply redirect to dashboard and can't call back to my app .please help me for it..thanks

Comment: @chetu Have you found any solution for Tumblr redirect problem